# Using AWK on a command to receive a part of its output

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use `awk` to extract part of its output and assign that to a variable but I cannot get AWK to work.

This is the command I am running:

`nc -v -z 192.168.8.216 9100 | awk '{print $NF}`'

This is the output

```
Connection to 192.168.8.216 9100 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

What I am trying to achieve is so that the output is only

```
succeeded
```

I just want the last part of the command so that I can assign it to a variable and run an if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command seems to be sending the output to `STDERR` and not to `STDOUT`.

Merge the `STDERR` with `STDOUT`:

```
nc -v -z 192.168.8.216 9100 2>&1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

---

> I just want the last part of the command so that I can assign it to a
>   variable and run an if statement.

If the purpose is to simply determine that the command produced the word *succeeded*, you don't need a variable:

```
[[ $(nc -v -z 192.168.8.216 9100 2>&1) =~ succeeded ]] && echo "Yes"
```

If you want to match the `!` too and ensure that it was at the end of line:

```
[[ $(nc -v -z 192.168.8.216 9100 2>&1) =~ succeeded\!$ ]] && echo "Yes"
```

Comment: will it be succeeded or succeeded!

Comment: @realspirituals By default fields would be split upon whitespace, so it'd be _succeeded!_

Comment: Yes. But the last value was `succeeded!` in OP's sample. Neverthless +1 for the answer

Comment: @realspirituals Updated the answer with options for checking the string too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the exit status:

```
nc -v -z 192.168.8.216 9100 && echo 'Yes' || echo 'No'
```